# Backtracking algorithm to create a "jumbled" but not random array

Tags: javascript, backtracking

I have written this backtracking algorithm to make a jumbled-looking array of 70 items from an input array of 10 items. The rules it needs to follow are:

1. No repeat item in each group of 5
2. No item appears in the same position in any of 3 consecutive groups of 5
3. Each item appears exactly 7 times in total

This almost works, but only if I make my input array bigger than my output array, which then breaks rule 3. If I make my input array length 70, the algorithm sometimes works but sometimes overflows.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />

 <title>Backtracking Pseudo Randomiser</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick=go();>Go</button>

<script>
function go() {
   
    function pseudoRan(input,output) {
        if (output.length==70) {
            output=listToMatrix(output,5);
            printIt(output);
            return; 
        }
                else {
                    var tmp=input.shift();
                    var mod=output.length % 5;
                    if (output.slice(-mod-1).indexOf(tmp)==-1 && output[output.length-5]!=tmp && output[output.length-10]!=tmp) {
                        output.push(tmp);
                        pseudoRan(input,output);
                    }
                    else {
                        input.push(tmp);
                        pseudoRan(input,output);
                    }
                    
                }
                    
                
    }
    
var input=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K"];
var output=[];
input=pool(input,70);
input=yatesShuffle(input);
pseudoRan(input, output);

    
    //analyse it
var freqs=output.byCount();
var strFreqs="";
for(a=0;a<freqs.length;a++){
      strFreqs+="Item: " + freqs[a].item + "   ..." + freqs[a].frequency + "<br />";
      document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=strFreqs;
    }
}
    
    
function pool(array,total) {
    var factor=total/array.length;
    var newArray=[];
    for (a=0;a<factor;a++) {
        for (b=0;b<array.length;b++) {
            newArray.push(array[b]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(newArray);
    return newArray;
}
    
function yatesShuffle (array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i); // no +1 here!
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        }   
    return array;
}
    

function listToMatrix(list, elementsPerSubArray) {
    var matrix = [], i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % elementsPerSubArray === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
        }

        matrix[k].push(list[i]);
    }

    return matrix;
}
    
function printIt(array) {
    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var str=" ";
        for (j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
            str+=array[i][j]+" ";
        }
        document.getElementById("1").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',str + "</br>");
        
        //console.log(array[i]);
    }
}
Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) a[a.length]= {item: p, frequency: o[p]};
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o[b.item]-o[a.item];
    });
}
    
</script>
<div id="1" style="font-family:'Courier New';"></div>
    <br />
<div id="2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In `Array.prototype.byCount` this line never gets run, because of the line before it: `if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;`

Comment: Thanks Mouser. I didn't write that bit - pinched it from another SO question so that I could get an analysis of my output. I don't think it's a problem?

Comment: I am pretty sure it works as intended.  Issue is that the problem you are trying to solve is not guaranteed a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not having too many inputs that's a problem.  If you run the code enough times I think that you will find that sometimes it will work, but other times, depending on the result of the shuffle, it's just impossible to fit any of the remaining inputs onto the output array.

It's like playing Solitaire:  There *might* be a solution at the start, but depending on the decisions you make as you go (picking items out of the input array) you might still lose.

---

You should at a minimum track if you have looped completely through the input array without any success.

If you have looped completely through the input list with no success, you never will.  Then you have a couple of options:

- Return the output you have and the remaining input (might be helpful just to see that it failed.
- Whether or not you log the failed attempt, you can then restart and then try again.  Just brute force attempts at random to find a solution.

---

One way to do it:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />

 <title>Backtracking Pseudo Randomiser</title>
</head>

<body>
<button onclick=go();>Go</button>

<script>
function go() {
       
    var tracker = 0

    function pseudoRan(input,output) {
        if (output.length==70) {
            output=listToMatrix(output,5);
            printIt(output);
            return true; 
        }
        else {
            var tmp=input.shift();
            var mod=output.length % 5;

            console.log('input.length::tracker ==>', input.length + '::' + tracker)
            
            if (output.slice(-mod-1).indexOf(tmp)==-1 && output[output.length-5]!=tmp && output[output.length-10]!=tmp) {
                tracker = 0
                output.push(tmp);
                return pseudoRan(input,output);
            }
            else {
                tracker++
                if (tracker > input.length) {
                    console.log('Failed this time.')
                    output=listToMatrix(output,5);
                    console.log('output-----------------------');
                    printIt(output);
                    console.log('input------------------------');
                    printIt(input);
                    return false // FAILED to finish
                }
                input.push(tmp);
                return pseudoRan(input,output);
            }
            
        }
                    
                
    }
        
    var input=["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K"];
    input=pool(input,300);

    // run until we get an answer
    do {
        var output=[];
        tracker = 0;
        // operate on copy of the data
        runInput=yatesShuffle(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(input)));
    } while (!pseudoRan(runInput, output))
    

        
    // analyse it
    var freqs=output.byCount();
    var strFreqs="";
    for(a=0;a<freqs.length;a++){
        strFreqs+="Item: " + freqs[a].item + "   ..." + freqs[a].frequency + "<br />";
        document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=strFreqs;
    }
}
        
    
function pool(array,total) {
    var factor=total/array.length;
    var newArray=[];
    for (a=0;a<factor;a++) {
        for (b=0;b<array.length;b++) {
            newArray.push(array[b]);
        }
    }
    //console.log(newArray);
    return newArray;
}
    
function yatesShuffle (array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i); // no +1 here!
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        }   
    return array;
}
    

function listToMatrix(list, elementsPerSubArray) {
    var matrix = [], i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (i % elementsPerSubArray === 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
        }

        matrix[k].push(list[i]);
    }

    return matrix;
}
    
function printIt(array) {
    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
        var str=" ";
        for (j=0;j<array[i].length;j++) {
            str+=array[i][j]+" ";
        }
        document.getElementById("1").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',str + "</br>");
        
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
}
Array.prototype.byCount= function(){
    var itm, a= [], L= this.length, o= {};
    for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
        itm= this[i];
        if(!itm) continue;
        if(o[itm]== undefined) o[itm]= 1;
        else ++o[itm];
    }
    for(var p in o) a[a.length]= {item: p, frequency: o[p]};
    return a.sort(function(a, b){
        return o[b.item]-o[a.item];
    });
}
    
</script>
<div id="1" style="font-family:'Courier New';"></div>
    <br />
<div id="2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By Jove that works! It seems to take between 1 and 6 attempts but in the successful attempt all 3 rules are obeyed. Thanks so much for solving this despite it being marked off-topic.

Comment: Great to hear!  Was only by running a bunch of times myself I saw it working occasionally.  Please consider marking as the solution :)

Comment: Certainly. I upvoted also but I'm too junior for that to count